# Indexes product in admin panel shopware 6 dosen'work ( never ending )

Tags: shopware

I imported products with property variants in the Shopware 6 with (API).
unfortunately, I did indexing in the admin panel instead of in console  **`bin/console dal:refresh:index`**, and now  I got stuck in an infinite loop.

When i try to run console `bin/console dal:refresh:index` I get this error

```
SQLATATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL error suggests that your MySQL database has issues, not Shopware. Make sure MySQL has enough memory available - in general, try to add an InnoDB buffer pool size of at least 50% of the size of the database. Perhaps, increase `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` - it should be 50s, but perhaps you need more.